# How do I make a batch file be able to run on other computers

Tags: windows, batch, environment-variables

When I create a batch file on my computer to execute `start c:\Users\________\Whatever\...`, it works on my machine.

How can I get it to work on someone else's machine, since their username isn't my username?

Answer (score 19):

You can use the Environmental Variable `%USERPROFILE%`. This works from Windows XP and on, and automatically detects the drive letter, and the folder path, to the current user's profile folder.

`start %USERPROFILE%\Whatever`

Answer (score 9):

You can use the [Windows environment variables](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html).  One you could use in this case would be `%username%`, which returns the current user's name.

ie:

`start c:\users\%username%\Whatever`

Additionally/alternatively, if you're specifically aiming for the user's profile folder (`<drive>:\users\<username>`) you can use the `%userprofile%` variable, which will return the full path to the current user's profile, which helps when targeting older OSs like XP (where it's `<drive>:\document and settings\<username>` by default), or where the profile folder has been moved to a different drive/location.

ie:

`start %userprofile%\Whatever`

There's several other variables in there that you may find useful in writing batches, I'd advise perusing the entire list. :)

Comment: I'd upvote if it wasn't for my last two Windows systems having kept the user profiles in `e:\users` and `d:\documents and settings`...

Comment: @grawity I tried to keep it generic by showing him the list of available variables, and not assuming they always want to target the user profile directory.  But hey point taken, so I updated it to cover the %userprofile% variable as well.

Comment: Dude, you just stole my answer :P

Comment: Not stolen, just expanded on my answer to make it more full.  Again, I tried to avoid making it specifically about the user profile directory originally, but apparently if I don't cover %userprofile% as well, then it's not a 'correct' answer. ;)

Comment: Don't worry, with the tongue sticking out in the comment, it's meant as a joke :)